# Android content Provider and Loader, uri not matching

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have an error when I try to read a table. I have a database with several table but my uri seems to not match.

My Content Provider :

```
public class CardContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
private StockCard stock;

public static String authority = "com.example.jean.cartememoire.CardContentProvider";
private static String path ="Cartes_table";

public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String THEME = "THEME";
public static final String QUESTION = "QUESTION";
public static final String REPONSE = "REPONSE";
public static final String DIFFICULTE = "DIFFICULTE"; //# = un chiffre
public static final String STOCK_TABLE = "Cartes_table";
public static final String STOCK_FACILE = "";
public static final String STOCK_NORMAL = "Cartes_tableCartes_table_facile_normal";
public static final String STOCK_DIFFICILE = "Cartes_table_difficile";
public static final String STOCK_EXTREME = "Cartes_table_extreme";
public static final String STOCK_IMPOSSIBLE = "Cartes_table_impossible";


private static final int ID_STOCK_TABLE = 1;
public static final int ID_FACILE = 2;
public static final int ID_NORMAL = 3;
public static final int ID_DIFFICILE = 4;
public static final int ID_EXTREME = 5;
public static final int ID_IMPOSSIBLE = 6;
private static final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    matcher.addURI(authority, STOCK_TABLE, ID_STOCK_TABLE);
    matcher.addURI(authority, STOCK_TABLE+"/*", ID_STOCK_TABLE);
    matcher.addURI(authority, STOCK_FACILE+"/*", ID_FACILE);
    matcher.addURI(authority, STOCK_NORMAL+"/*", ID_NORMAL);
    matcher.addURI(authority, STOCK_DIFFICILE+"/*", ID_DIFFICILE);
    matcher.addURI(authority, STOCK_EXTREME+"/*", ID_EXTREME);
    matcher.addURI(authority, STOCK_IMPOSSIBLE+"/*", ID_IMPOSSIBLE);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    stock = StockCard.getInstance(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = stock.getReadableDatabase();
    int code = matcher.match(uri);
    Cursor cursor;
    switch (code)
    {
        case ID_STOCK_TABLE:
            Log.d("Uri provider = "+code+" ", uri.toString()+" ");
            cursor = db.query(STOCK_TABLE, projection, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case ID_FACILE:
            cursor = db.query(STOCK_FACILE, projection, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case ID_NORMAL:
            cursor = db.query(STOCK_NORMAL, projection, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case ID_DIFFICILE:
            cursor = db.query(STOCK_DIFFICILE, projection, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case ID_EXTREME:
            cursor = db.query(STOCK_EXTREME, projection, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case ID_IMPOSSIBLE:
            cursor = db.query(STOCK_IMPOSSIBLE, projection, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        default:
            //long u = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            Log.d("Uri provider = "+code+" ", uri.toString()+" ");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Pas encore implémenté");
    }

    return cursor;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = stock.getWritableDatabase();
    int code = matcher.match(uri);
    long id;
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

    switch(code)
    {
        case ID_STOCK_TABLE:
            id = db.insert(STOCK_TABLE, null, values);
            builder.appendPath(STOCK_TABLE);
            break;
        case ID_FACILE:
            id = db.insert(STOCK_FACILE, null, values);
            builder.appendPath(STOCK_FACILE);
            break;
        case ID_NORMAL:
            id = db.insert(STOCK_NORMAL, null, values);
            builder.appendPath(STOCK_NORMAL);
            break;
        case ID_DIFFICILE:
            id = db.insert(STOCK_DIFFICILE, null, values);
            builder.appendPath(STOCK_DIFFICILE);
            break;
        case ID_EXTREME:
            id = db.insert(STOCK_EXTREME, null, values);
            builder.appendPath(STOCK_EXTREME);
            break;
        case ID_IMPOSSIBLE:
            id = db.insert(STOCK_IMPOSSIBLE, null, values);
            builder.appendPath(STOCK_IMPOSSIBLE);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Pas encore implémenté");
    }

    builder.authority(authority);
    builder = ContentUris.appendId(builder, id);

    return builder.build();
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = stock.getWritableDatabase();
    int code = matcher.match(uri);
    int i;
    long id;
    switch(code)
    {
        case ID_STOCK_TABLE:
            id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            i = db.delete(STOCK_TABLE, "_id=" + id, null);
            break;
        case ID_FACILE:
            id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            i = db.delete(STOCK_FACILE, "_id=" + id, null);
            break;
        case ID_NORMAL:
            id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            i = db.delete(STOCK_NORMAL, "_id=" + id, null);
            break;
        case ID_DIFFICILE:
            id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            i = db.delete(STOCK_DIFFICILE, "_id=" + id, null);
            break;
        case ID_EXTREME:
            id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            i = db.delete(STOCK_EXTREME, "_id=" + id, null);
            break;
        case ID_IMPOSSIBLE:
            id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            i = db.delete(STOCK_IMPOSSIBLE, "_id=" + id, null);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Pas encore implémenté");
    }

    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

My Fragment class that contains my Loader, in my function databaseview, I put my rows inside a List View :

```
public class ViewDeck extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    public static final String authority = "com.example.jean.cartememoire.CardContentProvider";
    public String[] from;
    public final int[] to = {R.id.idList, R.id.themeList, R.id.questionList, R.id.reponseList, R.id.difficultList};
    StockCard stock;
    ViewGroup container;
    ListView listView;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    Cursor cursor;
    private String focus;
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String table_name;

    public ViewDeck()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup c,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        container = c;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_card_editor, container, false);
        stock = StockCard.getInstance(container.getContext());
        from = new String[]{stock._ID,
                stock.THEME,
                stock.QUESTION,
                stock.REPONSE,
                stock.DIFFICULTE};

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        if (container != null) {
            container.removeAllViews();
        }
        Bundle f = getArguments();
        focus = getStockName(f.getInt("f"));
        databaseView(view);
        return view;
    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        Uri uri = builder.scheme("content").authority(authority)
                .appendPath("Cartes_table_facile").build();
        System.out.println("URI : "+uri.toString());
        //Log.d("Uri provider = "+code+" ", uri.toString()+" ");

        return new CursorLoader(container.getContext(), uri, from,
                null, null, null);
    }
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    public String getStockName(int d)
    {
        switch(d+1)
        {
            case CardContentProvider.ID_FACILE:
                return CardContentProvider.STOCK_FACILE;
            case CardContentProvider.ID_NORMAL:
                return CardContentProvider.STOCK_NORMAL;
            case CardContentProvider.ID_DIFFICILE:
                return CardContentProvider.STOCK_DIFFICILE;
            case CardContentProvider.ID_EXTREME:
                return CardContentProvider.STOCK_EXTREME;
            case CardContentProvider.ID_IMPOSSIBLE:
                return CardContentProvider.STOCK_IMPOSSIBLE;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Difficulté inconnue");
        }
    }

    public void databaseView(View view)
    {
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        System.out.println("DANS DATABASEVIEW");
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(container.getContext(), R.layout.card_stock, null, from, to,0);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if(cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
        LoaderManager manager = getLoaderManager();
        manager.initLoader(0, null, this);
        if(cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
        System.out.println("CA GAZ");
    }
}
```

EDIT : My error :

```
01-04 17:45:45.507 28655-28691/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
                                                   Process: com.example.jean.cartememoire, PID: 28655
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:153)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Pas encore implémenté
                                                       at com.example.jean.cartememoire.CardContentProvider.query(CardContentProvider.java:101)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1017)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:238)
                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompatJellybean.query(ContentResolverCompatJellybean.java:29)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat$ContentResolverCompatImplJB.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:57)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:125)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:59)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:37)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:296)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:54)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:42)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:133)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: `"I have an error when [...]"`, i dont see any error

Comment: Sorry I edited.

Comment: use `STOCK_NORMAL`, not `"Cartes_table_facile"`, BTW is `STOCK_NORMAL = "Cartes_tableCartes_table_facile_normal"` right?

Comment: I tried but It does the same error

Comment: so what does `uri.toString()` show on the logcat?

Comment: It showed -1, Thank you now it works, that was a really dumb mistake !!